# Сменить объявленную переменную при помощи деструктуризации

Tags: javascript

Надо сменить переменную, а так же задать значение по умолчанию для highIcon - это строка: "https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/2204/2204346.svg"
В результате Автопроверка не подтверждает факт объявления переменной при помощи деструктуризации.
Помогите понять, что я сделал неправильно? Или что не доделал? Моё решение ниже. Спасибо

```js
const highTemperatures = {
  yesterday: 28,
  today: 26,
  tomorrow: 33,
  
};
// Change code below this line


const { 
  yesterday:highYesterday, 
  today:highToday, 
  tomorrow:highTomorrow, 
  highIcon = 'https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/2204/2204346.svg', } = highTemperatures;

// Change code above this line
const meanTemperature = (highYesterday + highToday + highTomorrow) / 3;

console.log(highIcon);
```

Comment: Надо сменить переменную - сменили (highYesterday,  highToday, highTomorrow). значение по умолчанию для highIcon - задали.... что не так?

Comment: Не Обьявлена переменная 'highIcon' при помощи деструктуризації

Comment: в вашем коде highIcon инициализирована. что не так?

Comment: В этом весь вопрос - решение правильное, а автопроверка не пропускает. Возможно есть какой то дополнительный шаг - примитивный, а я его упускаю

Answer (score 0):

```
const d = {
  a: { name: 'x' },
};

const { a, b = '66' } = d;
// просто создались две константы
// const a = d.a;
// тут точно не уверен что под копотом
// const b = d.b ?? '66';
//НЕ
// const b = (d.b = '66');

//вместо того что на верху правилнее будет написать
// const { a } = d;
// const b = '66';
// потому что b не имеет нечего общего с d
```

Автопроверка(linter, typescript кампилятор или еще что то там) ругается, потому что странная операция попытка деструктурировать из обекта ключь которого нету

в `highTemperatures` нету `highIcon`.

правилнее будет так.

```
const { 
  yesterday:highYesterday, 
  today:highToday, 
  tomorrow:highTomorrow
} = highTemperatures;
 const highIcon = 'https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/2204/2204346.svg'
```

либо в обект добавить ключ highIcon: undefined/null/ссылку

Comment: Спасибо, но ничего не помогло.

Comment: @Boggi ошибка какая?